Is it possible to give effect if I am at certain height in Bedrock edition?
This is my first time using StackExchange and looking for so many Minecraft Bedrock commands command problem being solved. I'm looking fordward to ask the community about what I need...
Is there a command for me to detect where is the player height without caring where  X and Z the player is standing on?
For example, I want to give the player blindness effect if they are at y=5 height level, are there any commands?

Use the execute command to check the player's Y coordinate. For example, to check if a player is at Y=5, you can use the below command:
execute @a[y=5] ~ ~ ~ effect @s blindness 1 1 true

~ ~ ~ : means the command will be executed at the player's current X, Y, Z coordinates.
effect @s blindness 1 1 true: gives the player (targeted by @s, which stands for "self") blindness for 1 second with level 1.
You can also set it to "Always Active" to make sure it constantly checks the player's Y coordinate.
/execute @a[y=5] ~ ~ ~ effect @s blindness 1 1 true


Ohhh im sorry but your command didnt work on me, it told me a syntax error and unexpected @a
But i modify to this command though
/execute as @a at @s if entity @s[y=-61, dy=1] run effect @s blindness 1 10 true and its worked, thanks!
